# The EntityCollection has already been initialized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to update an existing entity

```
private void UpdateEfItem(MamConfiguration_V1 itemFromDb, MamConfiguration_V1 item)
{
    itemFromDb.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    itemFromDb.Description = item.Description;


   //references
   itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1 = item.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1;
   itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToGroups_V1 = item.MamConfigurationToGroups_V1;
}
```

I get the following error, when assigning Ui-Item to Ef-item:

```
itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1 = item.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1;
```

> The `EntityCollection` has already been initialized. The
>   `InitializeRelatedCollection` method should only be called to initialize
>   a new `EntityCollection` during deserialization of an object graph.

**Update:**

I have tried @Gert's way:

```
    private void UpdateEfItem(MamConfiguration_V1 itemFromDb, MamConfiguration_V1 item)
    {
        itemFromDb.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;

        itemFromDb.Description = item.Description;

        itemFromDb.StatusId = item.StatusId;

        itemFromDb.Name = item.Name;

        itemFromDb.NumericTraffic = item.NumericTraffic;

        itemFromDb.PercentageTraffic = item.PercentageTraffic;

        itemFromDb.Type = item.NumericTraffic;



        itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < item.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Count; i++)
        {
            var elementToAdd = item.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.ElementAt(i);

            elementToAdd.Browser = mMaMDBEntities.Browsers.Single(browserItem => browserItem.BrowserID == elementToAdd.BrowserID);

            elementToAdd.MamConfiguration_V1 = itemFromDb;

            itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Add(elementToAdd);
        }
```

and get the following error:

only when adding the `clear` and `add` commands

The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Comment: Is `MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1` and `MamConfigurationToGroups_V1` a `List<>`?

Comment: You must add ore remove items from the collections. Not replace them.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks, but now I get a new error. See my update

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Clear();

foreach (var item in item.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1)
{
     itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's likely happening is that SignalData is indirectly changing the subscribers dictionary under the hood during the loop and leading to that message. You can verify this by changing

Try This

```
 itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Clear();

 foreach (var item in item.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.ToList()) //.ToList()
 {
    itemFromDb.MamConfigurationToBrowser_V1.Add(item);
 }
```